Могут ли статические библиотеки, собранные с libstdc++ рантаймом использоваться в исполняемом файле, собранным с libcxx
Могут ли статическик библиотеки, собранные с libstdc++ рантаймом использоваться в исполняемом файле, собранным с libcxx? По идее, к библиотеке подтянется рантайм исполняемого файла, к которому она прилинкована. Но сложность в том, что в stl много шаблонного кода, который прибьется гвоздями к библиотечным бинарям, помешает ли разность шаблонов в данном случае?

Использование статических библиотек, собранных с libstdc++, в исполняемом файле, собранном с libc++, может привести к проблемам, главным образом из-за различий в реализации стандартной библиотеки C++.
libstdc++ и libc++ — это две разные реализации стандарта C++. У каждой из них есть свои особенности, включая различия в реализации шаблонов и специфических классов (например, контейнеров). Если ваш исполняемый файл использует одну из этих библиотек, а статическая библиотека использует другую, это может вызвать конфликты.
Шаблоны в C++ компилируются во время сборки, и их реализация фиксируется в бинарниках. Это означает, что если вы скомпилировали статическую библиотеку с libstdc++, а затем пытаетесь использовать её в программе, собранной с libc++, то возникнут проблемы. Шаблоны, определенные в одной библиотеке, не будут совместимы с шаблонами, определенными в другой, даже если они реализуют один и тот же интерфейс.
Резюмируя скажу, что смешивание статических библиотек, собранных с различными реализациями стандартной библиотеки C++, часто приводит к проблемам совместимости. Поэтому рекомендуется избегать такой практики и придерживаться единого стека инструментов для сборки вашего проекта.
Продуктивной вам работы)

Ответ настолько очевидно сгенерирован chatgpt…
